# Determine time - cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I think this is possible but how could I determine the user's time on their iPhone or iPod touch?

I'm making an app that changes with day and night time. So when it's 6 in the morning the background is sunny and when it is 9pm the background is dark.

Does anyone know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `NSDate`

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
```

And then you can extract the current time from this date object.

For more information, see the [Date and Time Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039i)